# Log4J timestamp

Tags: log4j

Looks like timestamp is not in sequence, means logging based on level.Can We display based on timestamp?

2009-02-19 14:47:01,288 DEBUG [com.catalystwms.core.persistence.TransactionContext]

2009-02-19 14:54:27,429 INFO  [com.catalystwms.tms.services.background.purge.PurgeManager]

2009-02-19 14:47:01,288 DEBUG [com.catalystwms.core.services.ServiceLocator]

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have immediateFlush set to false?

More info please, it's hard to answer this question.  Things you should include would be details on your configuration files, the logging statements in your code, etc. etc.

Comment: My question why it is not executed timestamp order like (1)14:47:01  (2)14:47:01  (3)14:54:27.I am expecting sequential order.